# What would be the best way to round an object to fit a shape?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm trying to round the body for a helicopter I'm modeling using a side and front view, however I was wondering if there would be any easier way to do it than moving every single vertex.

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: There are several ways in which you can move multiple vertices, two above all are Proportional Editing and Sculpting, but there are also other methods and add-ons. Obiuvsly, ecah one is suitable in one case an maybe not in another, it depends on your topology and the shape you would like to obtain. If you pack the background images in your file, maybe we'll be able to give a specific answer for your case.

Comment: Please show images with only the background and then next your 3d mesh on top in wireframe mode. You may need to compose images from single images. Its difficult to guess what particular helicopter is your goal.  Please show your modifiers if any.  Your images presenting that information are better than the reader guessing.   Use a fair number of vertices for mechanical mesh prominent features first, just as you did for the blades.  Smooth later with subdivide surface.  Model the mesh with windows and door placement and show us your work as an image.   Prominent features first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I think that for this situation it would be best to round off the geometry in edit mode.  Especially since you will (presumably) be  modeling more details to the mesh such as windows, doors, tail, etc. you will want the mesh to be more contoured.

The way I would do this would be to use the *smooth* function and then tweak it a little with proportional editing.

To do this first go into edit mode and select everything, then bring up the *specials* menu with <kbd>W</kbd> and select *smooth*.  You can tweak the smoothing by going to the bottom of the left toolbar (<kbd>T</kbd>) or hitting <kbd>F6</kbd>.  I used the default *smoothing* value of `0.5`, but increased the *repeat* value to `6`.

[image]

Then I would tweak the mesh around using *proportional editing*, turn proportional editing on with <kbd>O</kbd>.  You can set the falloff curve in the footer of the 3D view and adjust the falloff radius with the scroll wheel.  You can go into wireframe view and line up your model with the background image to help with the tweaking process.

Here is what I came up with after a little tweaking.

[image]